# Thing of social artifice

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Please tell me what is meant by 'social artifice' in the following

> Now historians are increasingly arguing that nation or national feeling cannot simply be described as 'invented' or 'imagined'. Such an approach presupposes that nation is a thing of social artifice, a symbolic formulation, rather than a natural essence.

Comment: Do you know what artifice means?

Comment: I do. It means trickery. But I somehow can't understand it in connection with 'social'.

Comment: We need some context... where is the quote from? Please **always** cite the sources for your question content.

Comment: I am reading a book on Modern History. It is a printed copy. This is the best I can cite. Source:  https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ki5NnXDnYK0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Policewala **Artifice** does not always connote a _negative._ Carefully read (for instance) this [entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/artifice?s=t) and think about _social **contrivance**_ or _social **strategem**_.

Answer (score 2):

> [artifice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artifice)
>
> 1. **b** :  an ingenious device or expedient
> 2. **a** :  an artful stratagem :  trick

*Social artifice* seems to be another way of expressing the idea of *social construction*, without getting into all the complicated details of sociology. Here, the author is saying that the presupposition is that "nation" is a social construct. This is similar to the notions that *gender* and *race* are social constructs.

> A [social construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructionism) or construction concerns the meaning, notion, or connotation placed on an object or event by a society, and adopted by the inhabitants of that society with respect to how they view or deal with the object or event. In that respect, a social construct as an idea would be widely accepted as natural by the society, but may or may not represent a reality shared by those outside the society, and would be an "invention or artifice of that society.

Answer (score 1):

"Artifice" CAN mean a trick or deceit. But it can also mean an invention, in the sense that the telephone is an invention. Collins English Dictionary gives definition 4: "a skilfully contrived device".

"Social" means having to do with society.

So a "social artifice" is an invention created by society.

So the writer here is saying that the idea of a "nation" is not something invented by society. I'm not quite sure what he means by that without more context, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Artifice is an archaic word, used more commonly in older writings. An example is:

> Man is a growth by law and not a creation by artifice.
> -James Allen circa1903.

If you look at the date of your writing and/or the education of your author, you may see a clearer option to his or her intent. After all, antonyms for ‘artifice’ are: fairness, candor, simplicity, and openness.

‘Social artifice’ could very well and I presumably believe to mean social manipulation or trickery.

Good words that once held specific definitions lose their given qualities when used loosely a few times, and then we are all left needing more context, when the answer should be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "social artifice" in this context to be pretty much as they define immediately after, i.e. that a nation is not simply an artifact of a society, it's not just "a symbolic formulation", but instead it has it's own intrinsic properties and uses.

In other words, the nation is not an artifact (accidental, emergent property, or consequence) of a society (social structure), but that is a proper entity onto itself.

Comment: My initial reading was the author was saying that **a nation is a thing of social artifice**.  I suppose that we need to agree what **such and approach** refers to, I thought it was to what the historians are arguing, rather than the thing they are arguing against.

Comment: Well, whether the author was arguing for a nation being a social artifice or not, the question was regarding what a _social artifice_ was.

Comment: I agree that you've given a nice explanation of **social artifice** (no down vote from me), the problem for me was that having come to the opposite understanding of the author's intention your **the nation is not an artifact** caused me to lose the flow of what you were saying. I'd be tempted to pull the definition of artifact out separately.

Comment: I think I interpreted the argument as negative because author stated that historians are arguing the issue *A*, which presupposes *B*  ....  I initially interpreted that as the author separating himself from the presupposition, when really by that clip the author could be entirely neutral towards the presuppositions validity.  I would follow your advice (extracting the definition) or even re-write it in the positive, but @Max's response does exactly that - and is well done. :)